# Start fragment in landscape mode

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments

Thanks in advance for your help.
I'm trying to load one of my fragments which is loaded from a drawerlayout activity in landscape mode by invoking

```
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

The fragment does load in landscape mode. I also have a runnable thread which starts from onStart() after the fragment binds to a background service and the runnable is killed onStop().

```
private final Runnable initCommands = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d(TAG,"running thread");
        if(isServiceBound) {

            //some code...
            new Handler().postDelayed(initCommands,800);
        }
    }
};
```

The runnable is launched after the fragment is bound to service:

```
private ServiceConnection serviceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
        ELMScanner.ELMScannerServiceBinder serviceBinder = (ELMScanner.ELMScannerServiceBinder) binder;
        scanner = serviceBinder.getService();
        isServiceBound = true;
        if (scanner.isConnected()) {

            Log.d(TAG,"init commands");

            new Handler().post(initCommands);
        }
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        isServiceBound = false;
        scanner.resetCommands();
    }
};

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG,"onStop");
    FRAGMENT_RUNNING = 0;
    if (isServiceBound) {
        getActivity().getApplicationContext().unbindService(serviceConn);
        Log.d(TAG,"unbinding service");
        isServiceBound = false;
        scanner.resetCommands();
    }

}
```

The problem I'm facing is coming from setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE). For some reason this method reloads the fragment not killing the first thread and as a result there are two instances of the thread running.

```
07-30 18:38:53.054    2940-2940/com.package/FuelFragment﹕ on Attach
07-30 18:38:53.054    2940-2940/com.package/FuelFragment﹕ onCreate
07-30 18:38:53.054    2940-2940/com.package/FuelFragment﹕ onCreatView
07-30 18:38:53.054    2940-2940/com.package/FuelFragment﹕ onstart
07-30 18:38:53.062    2940-2940/com.package/FuelFragment﹕ onStop
07-30 18:38:53.062    2940-2940/com.package/FuelFragment﹕ on Detach
07-30 18:38:53.070    2940-2940/com.package/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ cscCountry is not German : THR
07-30 18:38:53.070    2940-2940/com.package/FuelFragment﹕ on Attach
07-30 18:38:53.070    2940-2940/com.package/FuelFragment﹕ onCreate
07-30 18:38:53.242    2940-2940/com.package/FuelFragment﹕ onCreatView
07-30 18:38:53.250    2940-2940/com.package/FuelFragment﹕ onstart
07-30 18:38:53.257    2940-2940/com.package/FuelFragment﹕ init commands
07-30 18:38:53.257    2940-2940/com.package/FuelFragment﹕ init commands
07-30 18:38:53.328    2940-2940/com.package/FuelFragment﹕ running thread
```

My question: is there an alternative to setRequestedOrientation() that does not reload fragment?

Thanks.

Solution:

In case you're wondering how to fix this.

In the method onStart(), add the condition

```
int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

    if (orientation == 2) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ELMScanner.class);
        getActivity().getApplicationContext().bindService(serviceIntent, serviceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
```

This will ensure that the fragment only binds to service and runs the thread when it starts on landscape mode. Also make sure to add

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, no. Orientation changes need to restart the Activity/Fragment so the system gets a chance to reload all the resources.

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation%28int%29) for setRequestedOrientation:

> Change the desired orientation of this activity. If the activity is
>   currently in the foreground or otherwise impacting the screen
>   orientation, the screen will immediately be changed (possibly causing
>   the activity to be restarted). Otherwise, this will be used the next
>   time the activity is visible.

Your code should be able to handle being destroyed and recreated without messing up and creating two threads. It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish so I can't give you any further suggestions, but properly handling the activity lifecycle is necessary.